# Eclipse SVN Assistance to SourceForge

Tags: eclipse, svn

I cannot seem to get a project in Eclipse uploaded to SourceForge.  Basically I am going to Team -> Share Project -> SVN and it comes back with an error.  I am unsure what to do next as I have tired to figure out where the config files are, but no avail.  I also turned off the Windows (7) firewall.  It's Eclipse Indigo SR2.

mkdir --parents -m "Initial import." [svn+ssh://john@svn.code.sf.net/p/novaturtles2/code/trunk/GoogleJavaForm]
    The system cannot find the file specified.
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://john@svn.code.sf.net/p/novaturtles2/code/trunk/GoogleJavaForm'
svn: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: r u connected to internet using proxy?

Comment: I do not have a proxy to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting using svn+ssh?

[This](http://kiranpatils.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/svn-cant-create-tunnel-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/) blog post says they solved a similar problem through this:

```
 SVN_SSH Environment Variable value was like this[Won't Work]:

C:\Program Files\Putty\bin\plink.exe

It should be like this [Will work]:

C:\\Program Files\\Putty\\bin\\plink.exe

OR
C:/Program Files/Putty/bin/plink.exe
```

Comment: No, I am trying not to involve SSH at this time.  How do I disable it, as the error message says something about a tunnel?  Do I need it for SourceForge?

Comment: It looks like it according to the sourceforge wiki: 
["All SourceForge.net project services for developers (including shell service and CVS write access) are provided using SSH"](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SSH%20Client)

Comment: So much for the free life.  Looks like I need to work though Key Generation: PuTTY.  Will post if I need more assistance.  

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think you do _need_ to use keys. You can just use password authentication if you want and eclipse will prompt you for the password. It's strange: I've used svn+ssh at a couple of places and I've never seen this issue before but based on a few googles it seems quite common.

Comment: I generated a key for SourceForge, but no avail.  It looks like keys are only need for CVS.  Any way to turn a setting off in Eclipse to get rid of the "can't create tunnel" error?

Comment: I downloaded some SVN packs for Eclipse, and now I get the error below.  Does anyone know how to get past it?  Does anyone still use SourceForge?

checkout svn+ssh://john@svn.code.sf.net/p/novaturtles2/code/trunk -r HEAD --depth=infinity --force
    Network connection closed unexpectedly
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://john@svn.code.sf.net/p/novaturtles2/code/trunk'
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Had to do two things:

1. Download Eclipse SVN software: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php
2. Install the latest version of SubEclipse.  http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA
3. Setup the software with SVN Kit.  http://www.ranjankumar.in/working-with-svn-repository-in-eclipse/
4. Choose the second SVN selection in Eclipse.  The tunnel error does not exist after the default is set to SVNKit.